# O length de um array não atualiza

Tags: javascript

Ao dar `console` em um `array`, com um(1) objeto, e no `lenght` dele é obtido o retorno esperado, então atualizo o valor do array, adicionando uma nova posição, dou console no `array` e o retorno diz que existe dois objetos no `array` e então ao dar `console` no `lenght` dele me é retornado como se houvesse apenas um objeto.

**Porque o console não retorna o tamanho correto do array quando é dado `console` direto no `length`, mas retorna a quantidade certa quando o retorno é o próprio `array`?**

**Contexto**

Esse algorítimo era para calcular a melhor distância entre vários pontos. A função em si (menor_distancia) deveria receber as rotas, que é um objeto com as rotas que ainda não foram definidas, e o exclude, é um objeto com as rotas que deveriam ser removidos da nova rota porque já foram usadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Update 18/05/2018**
Atualizei o código na intenção de simplificá-lo e encontrar esse problema, que até então, encontra-se sem solução.

Projeto: https://jsfiddle.net/anndreyy/wbzbgj0z/3/

Comment: Qual o resultado que vc gostaria de receber nesses `console.log`s?

Comment: Na ultima linha "exclude.lenght" deveria retornar 2, conformeo console anterior, que retornou duas posições noa array.

Comment: Perdão, não entendi, pode me explicar melhor?

Comment: Cara eu fiz um testes aqui com a sua função, e os consoles logs retornam corretamente. Se eu passo um objeto dentro do array no parâmetro `exclude`, mostra apenas 1, se eu passo 2, mostra 2, e assim por diante. Não consegui replicar o problema em questão se entendi corretamente.

Comment: @guastallaigor você deu uma olhada no jsfiddle? La o meu problema está sendo replicado no console. Pra mim não faz o menor sentido esse erro, mas eu sempre replico ele. A principio estava fazendo no Angular, mudei para vue e agora estou fazendo direto no javascript e sempre nesse ponto eu tenho esse mesmo problema.

Comment: Seu fiddle não dá nenhuma saída no console pra mim. Parece que nem entra na função `menor_distancia`

Comment: @bfavaretto esse print que eu tirei é do console do fiddle. teistei agora novamente e está de acordo, pode dar uma outra olhada por gentileza?

Comment: Me diz uma URL atualizada do fiddle, naquela acima continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu acho que esse link está certo. Da uma olhada nesse video: https://youtu.be/NbrhkFZK9GU
https://jsfiddle.net/anndreyy/wbzbgj0z/2/

Comment: Olha, eu acho que é simplesmente uma questão de assincronismo. Quando você loga o objeto inteiro, o console só puxa os dados desse objeto, incluindo length, na hora que você clica na setinha pra abrir. Então o momento em que você loga o length 1 é anterior ao momento em que você expande o objeto no console e encontra length 2. Passe o mouse naquele `[i]` que aparece ao lado da seta de expandir objeto no console. Ele diz exatamente isso, que o objeto é calculado na hora desse clique.

Comment: No primeiro momento eu imaginei que era algo assim, póis se eu colocar um delay, usando setTimeout, o retorno é de acordo com esperado. Porém, queria entender o porque isso acontece, em que ponto isso acontece.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou corretamente

Comment: No ultimo console exibiu 2? Porque aqui continua 1.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer adicionar itens a exclude, altere a variável de destino para `exclude.push(rotas.destinos[i]);`

```
for (let i in rotas.destinos) {
    for (let j in exclude) {
        if (exclude[j].destino != rotas.destinos[i].destino) {
            exclude.push(rotas.destinos[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Tem algumas referências úteis sobre isso aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Marcelo, a ideia desse trecho é criar um `array` (destinos) com os valores `rotas.destinos` que não tenha os valores do exclude.